# Binding SizeChanged event to ViewModel

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, winui-3

My xaml code:

```
            <Grid>
                <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <Interactions:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="SizeChanged">
                        <Interactions:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding OnSizeChanged}"/>
                    </Interactions:EventTriggerBehavior
            </Grid>
```

In ViewModel:

```
public IRelayCommand OnSizeChanged => new RelayCommand(SizeChangedEvent);
private void SizeChangedEvent()
{
     // How to receive width and height at here
}
```

So my question is how to receive with and height in View model?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `CommandParameter` property and value converter.

**XAML:**

```
<Grid x:Name="grid">
    <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <Interactions:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="SizeChanged">
            <Interactions:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding OnSizeChanged}">
                <Interactions:InvokeCommandAction.CommandParameter>
                    <Binding ElementName="grid">
                        <Binding.Converter>
                            <local:SizeConverter />
                        </Binding.Converter>
                    </Binding>
                </Interactions:InvokeCommandAction.CommandParameter>
            </Interactions:InvokeCommandAction>
        </Interactions:EventTriggerBehavior>
    </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
</Grid>
```

**Converter:**

```
public class SizeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language) =>
        value is FrameworkElement fe ? (fe.ActualWidth, fe.ActualHeight) : (double.NaN, double.NaN);

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language) =>
        throw new NotSupportedException();
}
```

**View Model:**

```
public IRelayCommand OnSizeChanged => new RelayCommand<(double, double)>(SizeChangedEvent);

private void SizeChangedEvent((double width, double height) size)
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: This does not work. The CommandParameter Binding is evaluated only once. The OnSizeChanged method will always receive the size at that time, but never any changed values. Despite being accepted, the answer should be deleted. It already created confusion: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76817111/1136211

Answer (score 0):

Canvas cant have `sizechanged` event because Canvas uses **absolute positioning** as its layout technique for its contained child elements. As stated in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.canvas?view=winrt-22621#remarks)

> Because absolute positioning does not take into account the size of the app window, scaling, or other user-selected sizing, using a container element that adapts to different orientations and screen settings, such as Grid or StackPanel, is often a better choice than using Canvas. For more information, see Define layouts with XAML.

Edit: (based on comment)

For Grid you could directly bind the `sizechanged` event to the eventhandler in ViewModel like the example below

**Xaml**

```
<Grid SizeChanged="{x:Bind viewModel.Grid_SizeChanged,Mode=OneWay}">
</Grid>
```

**Xaml.cs**

```
  ViewModel viewModel { get; set; } = new ViewModel();
  public MainPage()
  {
      this.InitializeComponent();
  }
```

**ViewModel.cs**

```
  public class ViewModel
  {
     public void Grid_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
     {
          var height = (sender as Grid).ActualHeight;
     }
  }
```

Comment: sorry for lack of infomation, if put Canvas into Grid, Canvas will have sizeChanged event. Anyway, I just want to know how to receive size through sizeChanged event in viewmodel, so I update my question by changing Canvas to Grid.

Comment: I think (sender as Grid) violate MVVM, since view model should know nothing about view

Comment: This is not MVVM. Using this approach you might as well skip the view model completely and handle the `SizeChanged` event in the code-behind of the view. The view model should not have a dependency on a `Grid` element.

Comment: If I use SizeChangedEventArgs.newSize.width instead, does it violate mvvm? Or Can view model have SizeChangedEventArgs?