# WPF Binding.Converter in i:InvokeCommandAction.CommandParameter can only be called once

Tags: wpf, mvvm, ivalueconverter

When the Grid component size changes, I want to get its `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` properties so that the contents of the canvas in the Grid could be recalculated to fit. So, taking this post(https://stackoverflow.com/a/72573639/9949419) as a reference, I add an event trigger to the Grid and pass out its `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` properties trough a Converter. The code is as below.

Xaml code:

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
<!-- This is the Grid which I want to get its ActualWidth and ActualHeight properties.-->
<Grid x:Name="GraphicGrid">
    <!-- K value-->
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding RectItems}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding X}"/>
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Bottom" Value="{Binding Y}"/>
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Rectangle Width="{Binding Width}" Height="{Binding Height}" Fill="{Binding _Brush}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>      
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SizeChanged" >
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding OnSizeChanged}">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction.CommandParameter>
                    <Binding ElementName="GraphicGrid">
                        <Binding.Converter>
                            <!-- This this the value converter that passes the ActualWidth and ActualHeight properties to the event method.-->
                            <local:SizeConverter/>
                        </Binding.Converter>
                    </Binding>
                </i:InvokeCommandAction.CommandParameter>
            </i:InvokeCommandAction>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>        
</Grid>
```

View model code:

```
Public ICommand OnSizeChanged{get;set;}
Public MainWindowViewModel()
{
    OnSizeChanged = new RelayCommand<double,double)>(Resize);
}
public void Resize((double,double)size)
{
    // TODO:
}
```

SizeConverter code:

```
 public class SizeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value is FrameworkElement fe ?(fe.ActualWidth, fe.ActualHeight):(double.NaN,double.NaN);
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

When the project starts, `SizeConverter()` is called and get a (0,0) as a result(I assume this is the default value of the Grid before all elements have been loaded). However after start up initialization, no matter how I change the window size, only the `Resize()` method is called. The `SizeConverter()` is never called again, so the event parameter still remains (0,0).
Please someone tell me how to fix this problem. Thanks.

Comment: The code shown in the linked answer does not work. There is no reason for the framework to re-evaluate the CommandParameter Binding each time the command is invoked. Be aware that not every accepted answer on StackOverflow is correct.

Comment: Hi, Clemens. Any suggestions on how to get the Grid's actual size in MVVM mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing in MVVM that forbids that a view calls a method in its view model.

Assuming a public view model method like

```
public void Resize(double width, double height)
{
    ...
}
```

the Grid could have a `SizeChanged` event handler

```
<Grid x:Name="GraphicGrid" SizeChanged="GraphicGrid_SizeChanged">
...
```

that calls the view model method like

```
private void GraphicGrid_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ((MainWindowViewModel)DataContext).Resize(e.NewSize.Width, e.NewSize.Height);
}
```

Comment: Hi Clements. Thanks for your reply. Your suggestion works. But I don't know if it's supposed to do it in MVVM mode. I'm not experienced in WPF and I was told that the view model should create connection with the UI through binding not the code. Even```this.DataContest = new ViewModel()``` is not recommended. However, if it's ok to do so, in the view model constructor, I pass the MainWindow as a parameter and use  the ```Window.FindName()``` method to get the GraphicGrid. It worked as well.

Comment: You must not pass a view reference to a view model. That violates MVVM. The code here is code behind of the view, not part of the view model. It is a misconception that MVVM forbids code behind in the view. While it encourages data binding, code behind is valid as well. The important point is that the view model does not know the view while the view knows the view model, so it can safely make any method calls.